# Editor/Viewer to display and analyze Maven logs?

Tags: java, maven, logging, viewer

I use Maven for building Java projects. The output of Maven has immense size.
Is there an editor or log viewer that makes analyzing logs easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Baretail, "A free real-time log file monitoring tool"

http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

Answer (score 2):

`less` is your friend. You can also `tee` the output to some file and view that with your favorite editor.

```
mvn clean package | less
# or
mvn clean package | tee mvn.log
less mvn.log # using less as editor.
```

Answer (score 0):

I favor this approach.  It provides a log, the command run and wall clock time from start to finish.

```
function m-log
{

  # Build
  echo "mvn $* 2>&1"
  time mvn $* 2>&1 |tee mvn.log
  echo "command mvn $* 2>&1" >> mvn.log
}
```