# Maven Log viewer / Analyzer?

Tags: java, maven, logging

I googled for it. I do not see anything. 
I just want to view the maven log in a better way. Preferably a standalone tool not as an eclipse plug-in.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: i think it is hilarious that you need a special tool for reading damn build tool's log file.  Says something about the universe we ended up in.

Comment: You know that build log can become HUGE. And going through it is painful. I am sure many are of the same opinion :-)

Answer (score 1):

Latest developer snapshot of Apache Chainsaw can tail the log file.  It's available here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Here's how to get it to tail the Maven log file:

- Start Chainsaw
- Select File, Load Chainsaw configuration menu
- Select Process a log file checkbox, hit the 'Open File' button to browse to your log file
- In the 'Log file format' drop down, select 'MESSAGE'
- Click always start Chainsaw with this configuration (and optionally save it with a name you'd like to give it)
- Press ok

Comment: Will try this and let you know.

Comment: Thought it looks intuitive, its buggy and slow to the hell! Hope they will work on improving it.

Comment: Chainsaw keeps all events in memory, so if it's slow it's because you need to give the Chainsaw JVM more memory via -Xmx etc. Also, Chainsaw uses a cyclic buffer on each tab - defaulting to 50K events...tweak that setting in preferences if needed to avoid churning through the buffer.  I'd love to know what bugs you hit - feel free to reply here or to the log4j-users mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use Baretail, "A free real-time log file monitoring tool"

http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/
```

It costs 25$, but there is also a free version.

credit to [Editor/Viewer to display and analyze Maven logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278651/editor-viewer-to-display-and-analyze-maven-logs)